# Oracle Concurrent Program Running Long

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

Question.. I am not the DBA for my company but am I able to run a query to see what a program has completed and where its currently stuck on? I currently have one that has been running for almost 300 mins. The program is a seeded program named Create Accounting and Accounting Program. Just looking for any advice as I am not a DBA..

Oracle Applications : 12.1.3

I understand if this isn't an on topic questions, but I am actively searching the web. Thank you for any advice in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you need. The following query will give you the currently running SQL. You can limit it to the username, SID module or action.

```
SELECT s1.username,
       s1.sid,
       s1.module,
       s1.action,
       s2.sql_id,
       s2.sql_text
  FROM v$session s1
  JOIN v$sql s2
    ON s1.sql_id = s2.sql_id;
```

Also have a look at DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO:  SET_MODULE and SET_ACTION.